# MySQL fulltext search with no matches

Tags: mysql, database, search, full-text-search

---

Having this table:

```
CREATE  TABLE search (
`uid_search` INT(15) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`uid` INT(11), 
`type` VARCHAR(30), 
`strings` TEXT, 
UNIQUE (uid,type),
PRIMARY KEY (uid_search),
FULLTEXT (strings) ) ENGINE=MyISAM 
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
```

And inserting this data:

```
INSERT INTO `search` (`uid_search`, `uid`, `type`, `strings`) 
VALUES (1, 2, 'doc', 'Formación Primeros Auxilios');
```

Why none of this queries match the fulltext search?

`SELECT uid, type, strings, MATCH (strings) AGAINST ('Formación' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) as matches FROM search`

`SELECT uid, type, strings, MATCH (strings) AGAINST (CONVERT(_utf8'Formación' USING latin1) IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) as matches FROM agd_tmp.search`

I thinks something is wrong with UTF8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html):

> In addition, words that are present in 50% or more of the rows are considered common and do not match.

You need to insert more rows into your table.

Comment: I have more rows, but they are pre filtered with LIKE so more than 50% rows have that string. Any ideas?

Comment: I think use the `WITH QUERY EXPANSION` is the solution.